# Spring @Configuration in separate class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What is the difference between separate @Configuration classes and nested @Configuration classes?

Is it just a matter of taste, or some technical difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had always understood nested `@Configuration` classes to be [created in child application contexts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/modularizing-configurations.html), but now I come to look the documentation this doesn't appear to be the case any longer.

Instead, according to the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) it's a convenience to avoid unnecessary `@Import`ing or registering many `@Configuration` classes when bootstrapping.

**Edit**:
I just tried it in a SpringBoot 3 (Spring Framework 4) app and indeed the beans in my inner class appear in the same ApplicationContext as those in the outer class.

Comment: I don't think that inner classes weren't defining "child" contexts in earlier versions. The only such concept I remember is root servlet context vs web servlet context. You still can define that.